# I want my app to redirect to a custom view instead of the 'show' view(with the informations from show)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my app to redirect to a custom view instead of the 'show' view(with the informations from show)

**How it is:**

- User choose the equipment that he wants to borrow.
- User fills a form then click on the save button.
- App shows the information was successfully created on 'show view'.

**What I want:**

- User choose the equipment that he wants to borrow.
- User fills a form then click on the save button.
- App shows a view with the conditions and asks if the user agree with the terms.

How do I do that? just create a new view like: 'agreement.html.erb' with the same informations from 'show' view and redirect to it?

Comment: Why you not include the option for accept terms and condition on the same page and add a validation for acceptance. To show the terms and condition put a anchor tag with path of terms and condition detail page and set anchor tag property target ="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a second "show", you in fact should make a second "new"

```
resources :orders do
  get :approve, on: :new
end
```

In your "new" view, you now forward your submit to the "approve" action, like

```
= simple_form_for @order, url: approve_new_order_path, method: :get do |f|
```

Only in your "approve" view, you finally create the object, as you would normally do in your "new" view

Your "approve" controller action should look like

```
def approve
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])

  if @order.invalid?
    render :new
  end
end
```